# ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit clang

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, sdk

I am building an iOS messaging application with Layer+Parse. I have copied the files from the sample project into my exisiting application. At first I had over 40 errors upon building but I have worked it down to one. I have just added the Facebook SKD and I am left with this error:

> ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any help with getting this to go away would help greatly. I have already tried these steps:

> 1. Add the -ObjC flag to your project's Other Linker Flags build setting.
> 2. "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework modules" setting to YES in Build settings
> 3. Set "Enable Modules" (c and Objective-C) to No

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error and I fixed it by copying FBSDKCoreKit.framework into my project folder before adding it to the project.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue solved by adding the Facebook SDK path in Framework Search Paths

in xCode 
1- Select the project 
2- Open Build phase tap
3- Search on **Framework Search Paths** 
4- Add this path 
    $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-facebook-login/FacebookSDK

Comment: Removing old references to linked Frameworks is what I needed to do once I switched to using CocoaPods. Switching to CocoaPods is the best move I made in iOS in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

If you've switched from adding frameworks manually to using cocoapods, make sure you've removed any reference to FBSDKCoreKit (or any other FBSDK kit) from any existing project which is not the Pods project (look at "Link Binary With Libraries" under "Build Phases").

Comment: Also if you're using Pods, remember to load the xcworkspace NOT the xcodeproj in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for it in Build Settings. I removed Facebook from Cocoapods and it was still in other linker flags causing problems.